# How to set the log level from Spark in local mode from a Java application?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I run Spark 3.5.0 on a single Ubuntu Linux machine in local mode (no Hadoop). I build, package and execute the application with Maven, but no matter what I do, the console output from my application drowns in page after page of Spark logs that I want to stop.

- First I tried copying and editing the Spark provided log4j template file, setting all log levels to warn - for good measure I stored the edited version as both log4j2.properties & log4j.properties in the spark conf directory - no luck same non-relevant logs still printed.
- Then I tried various programmatic answers like for instance `Configurator.setRootLevel(Level.ERROR)` or `LogManager.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.WARN)` and other - no luck there either.

Any suggestions that actually work for this setup are very much appreciated!

Comment: does sparkSession.sparkContext.setLogLevel(loggingLevel) work for you?

Comment: `log4j.xml` works for me, but you need to know the exact names of the loggers, as apparently the setup for root doesn't work for all of them.

Comment: The setLogLevel seem to help but a lot of annoying log lines have already been printed at the point the spark session is created.
Really annoying that such a popular and widely used project as Apache spark does not solve a seemingly simple thing as making logging behve as described / expected....
@realSkeptic - have you tried disabling loggers explicitly after spark switched to log4j2? If so do you have some examples to share on how / what loggers you needed to disable?